# Trying to transition into different undergrad research area, how to approach professors in new area?

Tags: research-undergraduate, changing-fields

I am currently an undergraduate studying Physics and Aerospace Engineering. For most of my time I have been doing research in Applied Physics (optics, lasers, light-matter interactions stuff along those lines) and am looking to transition into propulsion or astrodynamics.

Unfortunately I have emailed a couple professors and have not gotten anything back from them (a few months ago). I don't know where to go now. What's your advice to get into one of these labs?

I am not keen on visiting face to face because I feel like as if I am invading his or her privacy and/or bugging them when they have such busy schedules.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions in no particular order:

- Try getting in touch with one of the grad students working in the
  labs you're interested in, they may be more responsive and they can
  potentially be your "in." Or they can give you very specific, individual, advice on how best to reach these professors.
- Take courses with the professors whose labs you are interested in,
  and impress them with your ability and your diligence in their
  course.
- Ask your current research advisor if they'd be willing to talk to the other professors you're interested in working with about possibly taking you on.
- Find out when their office hours are from students in the class(es) they're currently teaching. Visit them during office hours and ask if they have a few minutes to talk about research. Talk to them about research, and impress them.